# How do I add numbers to a column based on another column? (dictionary)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary with values that I need to add to a column in a dataframe. The dictionary looks like this:

```
{1:123, 2:345, 3:678}
```

and the column of the dataframe looks like this:

```
col1 
1     
2
3
```

and I want this result:

```
col1
1123
2345
3678
```

This is code I am using (replace function)

```
file['col1'] = file['col1'].replace(dict)
```

but replace() unfortunately deletes the value in column 1.

Comment: How does the logic work? Looks more like a concatenation rather than a sum. How about: `df['col1'] = df['col1']*1000 + df['col1'].map(yourdict)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to cast as `str` and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) - you can concatenate strings this way simply with `+`

```
df['col1'].astype(str) + df['col1'].map(d).astype(str)
```

[out]

```
0    1123
1    2345
2    3678
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

If it's necessary to cast back to `int` type, use:

```
(df['col1'].astype(str) + df['col1'].map(d).astype(str)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the col1 number  with 10*number_of_digits in col2 and add it to col2

ex:

col1=1 and col2=123

no of digits in col2 is 3

so col1=col1*10*3

now col1=col1+col2

if all the numbers of col2 are of same length then you don't need to find the length of each digit separatly just multiply 10 with the constant number and do the addition as mentioned above.